# How to avoid showing the same step in Flurry User paths Analytics

Tags: flurry, flurry-analytics

## Problem

Back in the day when I used Flurry, the User Path analysis was very useful in the sense that the first step was not repeated in subsequent steps like so:

[image]

But in the new Flurry version, the same step gets repeated like so:
[image]

## Question

How can I hide the same step in the new flurry version? It's very distracting and doesn't add any value (unless if I'm missing something)

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, the first step must be start session:

[image]